# How do i increase value by 1 value inside span inside button

Tags: javascript, jquery, express, ejs

My button :

```
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1 mark-complete-btn " id="<%=photo.id %>">
  Like <span id="likes-count-<%=photo.id %>"><%= photo.likes_count %></button>
```

I am using :  document.getElementById('likes-count-' + currentElement).textContent++;

But above code giving nothing. I want to be the above span value increase by one. I did any mistake?

Comment: You need to replace the value of the element, it will not update in place I also hope you note it will not alter what is store on the server.

Comment: For starters, your HTML is broken.  Always validate and fix the markup first before trying to debug the code.  Aside from that, can you provide a runnable example demonstrating the client-side functionality?  Because by itself the concept [works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/qg68c2j3/).

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the text of the element. You are also trying to increase a string, not a number. Thirdly, this is not going to update the value on your server, so hopefully you are makings some sort of Ajax/Fetch call to update the backend.

```js
function updateServer(id) {
  /*
  const data = {
    liked: id
  };
  fetch('https://example.com/profile', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log('Success:', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    });
  */
}


document.querySelectorAll('.mark-complete-btn').forEach(function(btn) {
  function update() {
    var span = btn.querySelector("span");
    var cnt = Number(span.textContent) + 1;
    span.textContent = cnt;
    updateServer(btn.id);
    btn.childNodes[0].nodeValue = "Liked ";
    btn.removeEventListener("click", update);
  }

  btn.addEventListener("click", update);
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1 mark-complete-btn" id="photo1">
  Like <span id="likes-count-photo1>">1</span></button>


<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm mr-1 mark-complete-btn" id="photo2">
  Like <span id="likes-count-photo2>">3</span></button>
```

Comment: in like button , i am getting liked text only , it is not showing likes count. currentElement.children[1].children[0].textContent =
                                "Liked";
                                currentElement.children[1].children[0].children[0].textContent++;

Comment: Word of advice.... put all this information in the question to start...

Comment: Edited it to update the text in the button along with the count

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```js
(function(window) {
    all_btns = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
    for(i=0; i< all_btns.length; i++){
        btn = all_btns[i];
        btn.onclick = function(){
            this.childNodes[1].textContent++;
        }
    }
})(this);
```

```html
<button id="123">
  Like <span id="likes-count">8</span>
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yo687rvx/1/

Comment: in like button , i am getting liked text only , it is not showing likes count. currentElement.children[1].children[0].textContent = "Liked"; currentElement.children[1].children[0].children[0].textContent++;

Comment: I am using above lines one by one

Comment: what is currentElement? @rudrasimha